# about GULP and application development

Tags: javascript, gulp

Can we use GULP for developing UI and then server, web services connecting them to the UI ? like a complete cycle to implement a simple application or something..

Comment: Did you even read what gulp is?

Comment: Yes,. but didnt understand much.. excuse me for my ignorance..

Comment: So hows life MJ.. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gulp is a build system or tool in javascript built on node streams. Basically its a task runner and does automated time-consuming and repetitive tasks involved in web development. So no, we cant use gulp alone to develop UI and complete application but with the help of gulp we can do front end web development.